# How to include an 'order' or 'index' column in a SELECT query?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, select, aggregate-functions

I'm using **Access SQL**. I want to add a `column` to my query that acts like a `row number` for each record, but because I'm using an **aggregate** function, the results have not ids themselves. Is there any function that generate some row numbers for this ? even like *Autonumber* or *index* or just the *order*. So my dummy SQL syntax is like:

```
SELECT [wanted autonumber column], product,Sum(amount) FROM Invoices_Items GROUP BY product
```

I guessed maybe it would be good if I create a **temporary table** for this query with an autonumber column but I don't know how to that.

Comment: You can use `product`'s ID column because you aggregate by product.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes but my `product`s have no ids

Comment: So what does "acts like an id" mean then? A product might have a different id in the next query.

Comment: @HenkHolterman you're right. Id is not a good word, Row number

Comment: So what if Access fills up the hole of a deleted record with a new one?

Comment: Why do you want to add this column? What is the business requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save the `GROUP BY` SQL as a named query in Access, you can use that as the data source for another `SELECT` statement which uses a correlated subquery to generate a row number.

So with this SQL saved as *qryInvoices_Items1* ...

```sql
SELECT i.product, Sum(i.amount) AS SumOfamount
FROM Invoices_Items AS i
GROUP BY i.product;
```

This query will add a dynamic row number --- the row number for a given product can be different from one run to the next if the underlying `Invoices_Items` data changes.

```sql
SELECT
    (
        SELECT Count(*)
        FROM qryInvoices_Items1 AS q2
        WHERE q2.product <= q1.product
    ) AS row_number,
    q1.product,
    q1.SumOfamount
FROM qryInvoices_Items1 AS q1;
```

I tested that SQL in Access 2007, and it returns the result I think you're looking for.  However, if I'm wrong about that point, please include `Invoices_Items` sample data in your question (as text, not a screen capture image) and show us the output you want based on that sample data.

Note a correlated subquery requires the db engine run that subquery separately for each row of the parent query's result set.  That would be a big performance challenge with a huge data set.  However, if your data set is small enough, the perform impact could be tolerable, or maybe not even noticeable.